# Как перевести JS скрипт в Php скрипт?

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток такой вопрос: Возможно ли конвертировать JS скрипт  в Php скрипт

```js
</script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 85) || (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && (event.keyCode == 73)) || event.keyCode == 123) {
        return false
    }
}
document.oncontextmenu = function(){
    return false
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ты ж понимаешь, что php работает **на сервере**, и понятия не имеет кто, где и на какие кнопки в браузере нажимает?

Comment: Нет я полный нуб

Comment: Ну тогда ознакомься и переосмысли задачу совю http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: Есть вот такой скрипт  <script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 85) || (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && (event.keyCode == 73)) || event.keyCode == 123) {
        return false
    }
}
document.oncontextmenu = function(){
    return false
}
</script> он не позволяет пользователям открывать код фрейма на странице. Возможно ли такое проделать не используя Javascript